# How to pass EventArgs to a function

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

I have a function that will draw a image to a form.

```
private void DrawImage()
{
    OpenFileDialog openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openfiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(openfiledialog.FileName, true);
        TextureBrush texturebrush = new TextureBrush(image);
        texturebrush.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
        Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillRectangle(texturebrush, new RectangleF(90.0F, 110.0F, 00, 300));
        formGraphics.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But i will not draw any image and same code works if i write in button click event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Same code as written in DrawImage()
}
```

The problem I think is it needs "EventArgs e" in it. I read some where in msdn but not sure.No idea what is the role of EventArgs in drawing image on form.

Is there any way that I can achieve this functionality.

Comment: From where (and when) do you call `DrawImage()`?

Comment: just put DrawImage() inside button1_Click, you dont need to use the EventArgs.

Comment: Don't use `this.CreateGraphics();` for such purpose. Pass a parameter of `Graphics` type to `DrawImage` method and use it for drawing. Also don't dispose it, it's not yours. Then feed the method with suitable `Graphics` object when you need. Specially, call `DrawImage(e.Graphics)` in `Paint` event of your `Form`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: The object you get from CreateGraphics *is* yours. You created it, after all. You shouldn't dispose the Graphics context you get in, e.g., the PaintEventArgs. The documentation also mirrors that: »Instead, you must call CreateGraphics every time that you want to use the Graphics object, and then call Dispose when you are finished using it.«

Comment: @Joey  probably we are talking about the same thing. When you create it using `CreateGraphics` the object is yours, but when it's passed as parameter to `DrawImage(Graphics g)` (like I proposed above) it's not yours and you should not dispose it. I said it because they may simply refactor their code and forget to remove `Dispose`. Here they does't need to use `CreateGraphics` because the drawing will disappear after an invalidation. They need to call their method in `Paint` event passing `e.Graphics` as parameter.

Comment: I am calling it in the constructor after InitializeComponent(). I know it will work from button click event irrespective of calling function or code in it. But it will not work if i call from constructor.

Comment: It's because your drawing will be disappeared if the form refreshes. You should call your method in `Paint` event.

Comment: By the way, when refactoring your code, don't keep that `OpenFileDialog` in  method. You should run it once and then draw image in `Paint` event of form.

Comment: @NithinB I shared some tips and a refactored version of your method. Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @Reza Aghaei. I made few changes regarding this.CreateGraphics and openfiledialog like this void DrawImage(String FileName, Graphics graphics){}.

Comment: You're welcome :) Both `FileName` or `Image` are OK.  Read the tips carefully they are really useful ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these tips to solve the problem:

- If you use `this.CreateGraphics` for drawing on your form, then your drawing will disappear if the form refershes, for example if you minimize and restore it. You should put drawing logic in `Paint` event.
- When refactoring your method, you should pass a parameter of `Graphics` type to your method and use it for drawing. Also you should not dispose passed parameter. You should pass `e.Graphics`  in `Paint` event to your method.
- In your method you should dispose your brush. Put it in a `using` block.
- When refactoring your method, you should move the part of code which shows a dialog to out of your method. You should call it just when you need not in `Paint` event handler.
- Preferably Don't use `Image.FromFile` to load image, it locks the file until the images disposes. Instead use `Image.FromStream`.
- You are using a rectangle with `0` as `Width`. So if you draw even using current method, you will not see any result because of width of rectangle.

**Code**

```
Bitmap image;
private void DrawImage(Bitmap image, Graphics g, Rectangle r)
{
    using (var brush = new TextureBrush(image))
    {
        brush.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
        g.FillRectangle(brush, r);
    }
}        

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (var s = new System.IO.FileStream(dialog.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            image = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(s));

        this.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (image != null)
        this.DrawImage(image, e.Graphics, new RectangleF(10, 10, 200, 200));
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to attach event handlers to events.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

You don't *have* to. For your case, just ignore them. They may be, however, useful sometimes. Read full answer to understand.

---

## Full answer

When dealing with events, you receive a generic `EventArgs` object and if you write a custom event, you may want to receive a custom implementation of `EventArgs`.

To make things simple, consider it a base class that holds event-related data.

So, for instance, if you are implementing a click event, as shown, you will receive two arguments: a source for the event and a holder for the event-related data.

Sometimes this is just useless. As on your sample. You don't have to receive it, nor use it. You may, however, perform some check on the source or the event data but that's not the goal of your code so both are just useless here.

As for me, I prefer to keep **my** methods apart from events, and call them from the event. I do place every event binding in a "group" on the bottom of the class to keep everything clean and readable. That's just a suggestion, you *have* to find your very own way of keeping code.

---

For the sake of this answer, here follows two samples:

#### 1. Useless arguments

This sample just closes a form or window.

```
public void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Close(); }
```

#### 2. Usefull arguments

Consider a component with a data grid of some type which fires a SelectedRowsChanged event with the id's (PK) of the selected rows.

```
// Event declaration. You can, after that, bind it elsewhere.
public event EventHandler<SelectionEventArgs> SelectedRowsChanged;

// This is the local implementation wich will fire the event.
// Here you invoke the event with the selected rows id's.
public void OnSelectedRowsChanged() { if (SelectedRowsChanged != null) CustomSelection(this, new SelectionEventArgs(this.SelectedRows)); }

// This is the custom implementation of the EventArgs to include the
// event-related data (row id)
public class SelectionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public int[] SelectedRows{ get; private set; }
   public SelectionEventArgs(int[] selectedRows) { SelectedRows = selectedRows; }
}

// ... then, somewhere else on your code

this.myControl.SelectedRowsChanged += myControl_SelectedRowsChanged;

public void myControl_SelectedRowsChanged(object sender, SelectionEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.SelectedRows.Length > 0) { /* do something */ }
}
```

---

For the strong of heart, you may play a bit with lambda too. So, instead of:

```
this.button1.Click += button1_Click;
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { DoSomething(); }
```

you may have just this:

```
this.button1.Click += (s, e) => { DoSomething(); };
```

As on the first sample, event args are there (`(s, e)`) but they are just useless for the `DoSomething` method.

Lambdas are available in C# 5 (.NET 4.5) and above.
Sometimes it's easier to just do this in a form constructor or something alike.